# stop the dynamic upload of xhr files

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I use ajax for the dynamic upload of many files, I would like to add a button that would stop the upload on the server and browser side. I tried to add XHR, unfortunately it does not work I can not deal with it

My code:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.start-upload', start_upload);


function start_upload(){
    $('.start-upload').remove();
    $('.upload-content').append('<div class="button blue stop-upload">Stop upload</div>');
    var upload = 0; // upload one file, 2, 3, 4



    $(document).on('ajax', function(){
        if (uploadfiles[upload]=='undefined'){ return false; }

        var file = uploadfiles[upload];
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file);
        var XHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
           'type':'POST',
           'url':'s1/index.php',
           'data': form, 
           'contentType': false,
           'processData': false,
           'success': function(r){



               upload++;
               $(document).trigger('ajax');
           }
        });

    }).trigger('ajax');
}


$('body').on('click', '.stop-upload', stop_upload);
function stop_upload(){
     XHR.abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var XHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
```

This will not be the same `XMLHttpRequest` instance that the `jQuery.ajax()` call uses in its underlying code. It will be using its own instance.

From the documentation:

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
>
> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods:
>
> ...
>
> abort( [ statusText ] )

So if you want to abort the ajax call, save the result of `jQuery.ajax()` and call abort from it, and not a new instance of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var request;

//inside the callback
request = $.ajax({});

//Some Other Place
request.abort();
```

Comment: @WojciechUrbaniak, expand on doesn't work. What did your code look like when you edited it? Did you get some kind of error?